# linux - give the list of file in date sorted way with modification time before 2 days

Tags: linux

I want to list the file from linux directory with some file filter and modification time before 2 days, but thing is list also should give the result in the sorted way .. oldest file first .

kindly help me with this .

thank you .

Answer (score 1):

In this command, I find sample files in directory_name without recursive search (-maxdepth 1), print time in Unix-format (for easy sorting) and sort it.

```
find directory_name -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +2 -printf '%T@\t%p\n'|sort -n
```

Comment: And then remove the time from the output by using `| cut -d' ' -f2`.